# failed to start Virtual Device in Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: networking, virtualbox, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualization

I was tired to do everything indicated on net. I am using Genymotion to start virtual device but when i start device it's gives me that error
[image: Error Image]

Note: When i start virtual operating System Linux it's successfully started.But when i am trying to start Samsumg Galaxy S2 it's give me error

> Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Samsung Galaxy S2 -
>
> 4.1.1 - API 16 - 480x800. Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter'
>
> (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND). Failed to attach the network LUN
>
> (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND). Result Code: E_FAIL (0x80004005)
>
> Component: ConsoleWrap Interface: IConsole
>
> {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I am using Windows 10 Pro.Before update Windows 10 it's virtual device start's successfully. But when i update windows it's not running. I try everything. uninstall reinstall VB. But it's not working. Please someone helps

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem as you, tried everything, but the solution is really easy:

1. Open network center
2. Change adapter settings
3. Right click your Virtualbox host-only adapter and select Properties
4. Enable "Virtualbox NDIS6 Bridget Networking Driver" (if it's disabled - if it's not, see next)

If the checkbox in step 4 was disabled, VB should work just fine now (no reboot needed). Otherwise repeat steps 3-4 for *every  network adapter* you have (Ethernet, WiFi...) and always uncheck the NDIS6 checkbox -> apply -> check it again -> apply.

Hope this helps - worked for me on 2 different machines (it seems that this is caused by last Windows 10 update - thanks Microsoft for wasting another 4 hours of my life).

Comment: Thanks bro...but i uninstall windows updates after that i am getting this [error](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/13713). I created another host-only adapter after restart it's successfully running.

Comment: Thank you for saving (at least!) 4 hours of my life! The same Windows update had been in a failed-install state for a couple months, and when I finally fixed that sufficient for it to finish installing I was rewarded with this error. ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. Same problem here but linked to Vagrant not being able to pull up any VM anymore. Solved as you described :)

Comment: Absolutely incorrect answer cannot believe this is being suggested!  The HOST-ONLY adapters (Virtualbox/VMware) DO NOT BRIDGE anything - they are HOST ONLY!  Enabling BRIDGING on them is incorrect. Don't believe me? Install VMware and look at it's adapters the BRIDGING adapter DOES need it enabled - the HOST ONLY does not and should not. If you need it - you have something mis-configured.

Comment: For me this worked https://askubuntu.com/a/1320895/792047